# Performing Calculation on Objects in python class

Tags: python

I have a class in python that will need to perform calculations on objects which get their data from lists that loop though and add a new row from a csv every time.

How can I call the objects defined in `__init__()` into the `calcA()`, `calcB()`, `calcC()` methods to perform a calculation for every row stored in it and then write the results back into the object defined in `Calculation` without changing the data already stored in `__init__`?

I will then use the objects from `__init__` and `Calculation` to write to columns in a `csv`

```
class CreateObjects():
    def __init__(self, OjectID, ObjectPrice, ObjectNum, Objectzone, ObjectTicket, Multiplier):
        self.OjectID= OjectID
        self.ObjectPrice= ObjectPrice
        self.ObjectTicket= ObjectTicket
        self.ObjectNum= ObjectNum
        self.Objectzone= Objectzone
        self.Multiplier = Multiplier

    def Calculation(self, A, B, C):
        self.A = A
        self.B = B
        self.C = C

    def calcA():
        pass

    def calcB():
        pass

    def calcC():
        pass
```

Comment: There are a view issues with you code: first, `def Calculation` should not have `:` before the parethesis.

Comment: Are `calcA()` (and B and C) functions outside of the class or are they methods? Because if they are methods then they should have a first parameter (called `self` by convention) that is the class instance reference.

Comment: @Ralf sorry made some edits while typing up the question. They are contained in the CreateObjects() class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `calcA()` is a method, then it should have a first parameter (called `self` by convention). You can use that to access all properties / attributes of the class instance.

For example:

```
class CreateObjects:
    ...
    def calcA(self):
        # this will allways work, because '__init__()' is allways
        # called before this method
        print(self.OjectID)

        # this will only work if the method 'Calculation()' was called
        # before this, because otherwise 'A' will not be defined yet
        print(self.A)
```

Comment: ` def calcA():
        self.ObjectPrice + self.Multiplier = self.A `  Would this be correct then for example to perform a calculation and then store it back in the objects in Calculation? What would be the correct way to call 'Calculation' to define those objects if I only want to store the results of a calculation result back into them for every row in the __init_ objects

Comment: The line `self.ObjectPrice + self.Multiplier = self.A` will not work; what are you trying to do? If you want to assign the result of the sum to `A` then it should be the other way around: `self.A = self.ObjectPrice + self.Multiplier`

Comment: Also, if you do `self.A = ...` then you are assigning a new value to `self.A`, meaning the old value will be lost. If you want to add a value for each line you need to use some kind of list or collection and append to that, maybe like `self.A.append(self.ObjectPrice + self.Multiplier)`

Comment: Thanks! that makes sense now. Since there is an entire csv file colum stored in for example 'ObjectPrice' Im guessing I would have to add a loop onto that as well for every row stored in it

Comment: Yes. I suggest you name your variables and attributes something more meaningful to avoid confusion; for example change `ObjectPrice` to `object_price_list`. This will help you on your further questions on StackOverflow